# Access dashboard on freshly installed OpenStack from outside world

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openstack

I followed [this guide](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single-installer.guide.html) to install a single machine setup, and it appears to have worked. I get the `openstack-status` screen and it's green across the board.

[image: openstack-status]

Now I want to access the dashboard at 10.0.3.12/horizon from another machine as I only have SSH to the host machine. But it timeout :(

So I googled a bit and tried to setup a bridge but couldn't get that to work so abandoned that approach.
Then I read about [Associate floating IP addresses](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/floating_ip_allocate.html) which says:

> After you associate the IP address and configure security group rules for the instance, the instance is publicly available at the floating IP address.

Sounds pretty good to me! So I fire the `nova` command and *'nova' is not a known command*... what gives?! OpenStack uses nova - I think... Why isn't nova installed then? Am I doing it wrong? Ok I know neutron is installed as the `openstack-status` says it's checking neutron something and that reports back as a success. So I fire `neutron` and *'neutron' is not a known command*. **!"#%@**

It seems no matter what I try I end up in a ditch.

I need help! What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this problem with iptables forwarding:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.12:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.3.12 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

(replace `eth0` and `10.0.3.12` to yours)